# How do I clear the back history of my app only if user performs an action?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am having trouble controlling the behaviour of Intent.

The use case is this:
When a user is browsing the internet in Chrome and clicks on menu, share and then on my app, a screen opens allowing the user to edit certain information. When the user is done editing he or she can click on "Done, choose chat to post". Then a new activity opens with all the available chats.

At this point, the user should be able to press the standard back button to return to the editing activity or the user can click on a chat to post.

If the user clicks on a chat and posts the link, a new acitivity starts the chat allowing the user to continue chatting or press back to return to the browser and NOT to the "choose chat" activity or the "edit information" activity.

so basically i want to be able to do the following:

use case 1: [browser] --> [share] --> [edit info] --> [choose chat].  (back button returns to [edit info].

use case 2: [browser] --> [share] --> [edit info] --> [choose chat] --> [open chat] . (back button return to [browser].

I have tried various combinations of Intent flags when starting [edit info] and [choose chat] but none is giving me the behaviour that I am trying to achieve.

So my question is: How do I clear the back history of my app only, allowing the user to return to the previous app BUT ONLY when the user finishes the prescribed process (in this case, actually posting the link in a chat)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On creating the Activity for Open Chat, use this flag

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will try out the solution soon,, kinda busy with something else right now.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it returns me to edit info once i finish the post

Comment: @Rengens       It returns me to [edit info] one i finish the post and click on back while i am inside [open chat].. (had to clarify my previous comment)

Comment: your answer works, All i had to do was make " [share] --> [edit info] --> [choose chat] " into fragments, and put them in the same activity. So that when the chat opens, the previous activity is gone which contains all those fragments.